# Top k students in each class in MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables that looks like this:

```
Class  Name  Score  Top
1      Amy    90     X
1      Ben    70     X
1      Chu    80     X
2      Don    60     X
2      Elf    65     X
2      Fez    75     X
2      Ges    35     X
2      Han    40     X

Class NumToppers
1      2
2      3
```

I want to find Top "NumToppers" from each class and accordingly update "Top" field:

```
Class  Name  Score  Top
1      Amy    90     Y
1      Ben    70     N
1      Chu    80     Y
2      Don    60     Y
2      Elf    65     Y
2      Fez    75     Y
2      Ges    35     N
2      Han    40     N
```

I have 100s of "Classes" in my real data. So, although data looks toyish, no toy solutions please.

Comment: What defines the 'NumToppers'? Is it just bottom of class = 'N', and everyone else = 'Y' - or something else?

Comment: @SimonRigharts No. It is the number of toppers for each class. I made a small change and it should be much clear.

Comment: Oh I see now. One question though - what happens in the case of multiple students having the same score. I.E. if the class scores are (90, 80, 80, 60, 40) and your NumToppers for that class is 2, do you A: mark one of the 80 scores as top and the other not (randomly?), B: mark both of them or C: mark neither of them?

Comment: @SimonRigharts .... one of them randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [this excellent page on selecting the 'greatest-n-per-group'](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), here's the query I came up with. In retrospect it is basically identical to @BassamMehanni's answer, except that there is no `ROW_NUMBER()` function in MySQL.

This assumes you have tables `class` and `toppers`.

### Solution:

Note: if you have a primary ID on the `class` table that isn't the compound `(Class,Name,Score)` combination, use that instead for the join condition marked `#@@`.

```
set @class='';
set @rank=1;
UPDATE class         
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT Class,Name,Score,
       @rank:=if(@class=Class,@rank+1,1) as rank, 
       @class:=Class as dummy 
  FROM class ORDER BY Class,Score DESC) c
ON c.Class=class.Class AND c.Score=class.Score  #@@
   AND c.Name=class.Name                        #@@
LEFT JOIN toppers
ON c.Class=toppers.Class
SET Top = (CASE WHEN rank <= NumToppers THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END);
```

### Explanation

Basically, this query:

1. numbers the rows of `class` from top-to-bottom by score, within each class. That is, ranks each student within each class.
2. selects rows of `class` for which the `rank` is `<= NumToppers`, for each class.
3. Updates these.

For step 1, see the following (from the link I referred you):

```
set @class='';
set @rank=1;
SELECT Class,Name,Score, 
       @num:=if(@class=Class,@rank+1,1) as rank, 
       @class:=Class as dummy 
FROM class ORDER BY Class,Score DESC;
```

This looks through every row of `class` (after by sorting by class and descending score) and sets the `rank` to 1 if we're on to a new class, or to `rank+1` if we're within the same class.

For step 2, we do a JOIN with `toppers` on `class` and pick the top `NumToppers` rows for each class:

```
set @class='';
set @rank=1;
SELECT *                                          # NEW
FROM toppers                                      # NEW
LEFT JOIN                                         # NEW
  (SELECT Class,Name,Score,                       #\
       @rank:=if(@class=Class,@rank+1,1) as rank, # |(same as step 1)
       @class:=class as dummy                     # |
  FROM class ORDER BY Class,Score DESC) c         #/ 
ON c.Class=toppers.Class                          # NEW
WHERE rank <= NumToppers;                         # NEW
```

Finally, we update on these conditions (step 3). However we have to do `UPDATE class` explicitly so we have to add in an extra `JOIN` of step 2 with `class`:

```
set @class='';
set @rank=1;
UPDATE class                                      # NEW
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT Class,Name,Score,
       @rank:=if(@class=Class,@rank+1,1) as rank, 
       @class:=class as dummy 
  FROM class ORDER BY Class,Score DESC) c
ON c.Class=class.Class AND c.Score=class.Score    # NEW (join condition)
   AND c.Name=class.Name                          # NEW (join condition)
LEFT JOIN toppers
ON c.Class=toppers.Class
SET top = (CASE WHEN rank <= NumToppers THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END); # NEW
```

If you have a primary ID on `class` that is preferrably not compound (ie a one-column ID) then join on that instead.

Comment: +1 did not know that Row_Number does not exist in MySql such a great tool in PlSQL and TSQL, good thing there is a way to replicate it though :D